# I try to install python package (collections) by using this command (sudo pip install collections) but these errors appear i want the solution?

Tags: python, pip, requirements.txt

but i got this errors i want the solution

(ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement collections (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for collections)

i do this command (sudo pip install collections) but these errors appear any one here know the solution

Answer (score 1):

This [package](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html) does not need to be installed and is automatically installed on Python

```
import collections
```

Comment: but this is error appear (collections could not be resolved)

Comment: it's mean the module already have in python and no need to install it. just enter the code : 'import collections'.